# Updating a list within a dictionary

Tags: c#

I'm trying to update a list within a dictionary. I'm not sure whether my approach is the correct way to go about my problem.

I want to map keys against a list and thought I could do this with a dictionary

```
Dictionary<Occupation, List<Person>> personsWithOccupation = new Dictionary<Occupation, List<Person>>();

OnPersonAdded(Person person){ 
    Occupation occ = person.GetOccupation();
    personsWithOccupation.Add(occ, UPDATE LIST);
}
```

I understand that I could grab the list out of the dictionary, update it and put it back into the list, but my question, Am I going about this the wrong way?. Should I be mapping these values in a different, more efficient approach?

EDIT:

I'm going to consume these values like this

```
public List<Person> GetPersonsWithOccupation(Occupation occ){
     return personsWithOccupation[occ];
}
```

Comment: How to map depends on how you are going to consume those values? Can you show how you are going to use `personsWithOccupation` variable?

Comment: You can just update the list you currently have `dict[occupation].Add(person)` but wouldn't it be easier to just have one list `List<Person>` and have occupation as `Person` property? The you could have use something like `list.GroupBy(p => p.occupation)`;

Comment: @Fabio Thanks, I've updated how I will consume the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add new person to occupation just like this:

```cs
OnPersonAdded(Person person) { 
    Occupation occ = person.GetOccupation();
    if (!personWithOccupation.ContainsKey(occ))
        personWithOccupation[acc] = new List<Person>();
    personsWithOccupation[occ].Add(person);
}
```

Comment: You can check if the occupation exists to avoid exceptions

Comment: Perhaps cleaner and avoids the double lookup of the key: `if (!personsWithOccupation.TryGetValue(occ, out var list) { personsWithOccupation[occ] = list = new List<Person>(); } list.Add(person); `

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 I do it even more concise see below

Comment: @Charlieface part of being concise is being *clear* and I'd argue shoving everything on one line that way makes it difficult to reason about--especially for someone who needs to ask this type of question to begin with

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use this code, avoiding double lookups and it's also pretty concise:

```cs
(personsWithOccupation.TryGetValue(occ, out var list)  // see if we have the key already
    ? list                  // return list
    : personsWithOccupation[occ] = new List<Person>())  // if not add list and return it
.Add(person);     // add to list
```